# Tkinter and Tix demo or showcase application?

Tags: python, tkinter, tix

Is there a showcase (demo) application with all Tkinter and Tix features and widgets?

For example, wxPython download includes a "wxPython Demo" application which not only demonstrates the widgets, but also provides the source code and some comments on it, which I liked a lot.

But now I have to stick to Tkinter and Tix only, and as of those - there is some real good documentation, even with patterns explained, but there is no a showcase I could find, so I basically have to copy-paste lots of code from docs to my sample app to understand what it looks like in real.

P.S. Tix is really wanted, not only Tkinter...

Comment: something like that here: http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/A_tour_of_Tkinter_widgets

Comment: Yep! This is pretty much what I meant indeed. Thank you. Would be nice if there is some "widget tour" for Tix as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this message:
http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/0b42abf092120140

Answer (score 1):

The [Python wiki page on TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) is a good starting point - listing many resources. The TutorialsPoint site seems to be one of the few that gives a reasonable [visual overview of the TkInter widgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm). Also there is an overview of the [basic tk widgets](http://wiki.tcl.tk/490) on the tcl.tk site.